# ffmpeg subtitles does not copy text, only timestamps when converting ass to srt

Tags: ffmpeg, video, subtitles

I've been trying to convert an mkv to mp4 without loosing subtitles, however nothing has worked so far. I've narrowed it down to some sort of bug (I think). I can extract the subtitles from the mkv to a .ass file which works perfectly

The first part of the ass file looks like this, as an example

```
[Script Info]
ScriptType: v4.00+
PlayResX: 384
PlayResY: 288

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, AlphaLevel, Encoding
Style: Default,Arial,16,&Hffffff,&Hffffff,&H0,&H0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,10,10,10,0,0

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:01.60,0:00:04.70,Default,[ VACUUM RUNNING ]
Dialogue: 0,0:00:12.45,0:00:14.68,Default,HURRY UP
```

However converting this file to .srt produces an output file with timestamps but no text.

```
1
00:00:01,600 --> 00:00:04,700


2
00:00:12,450 --> 00:00:14,680


3
00:00:14,680 --> 00:00:16,120


4
00:00:16,120 --> 00:00:18,620
```

I've tried specifying the encoding and the codec but it still doesn't work. This is the command I used, however not specifying the codec and encoding changes nothing.

```
ffmpeg -sub_charenc UTF-8 -i subs.ass -c:s srt subs_test.srt
```

There are some non ascii characters, notably ♪♪, hence specifying the encoding. `chardetect` reports:

```
subs.ass: utf-8 with confidence 0.938125
```

I'm not familiar particularly with `chardetect` so I don't know if 93% is low but that looks like its probably utf-8

I also used hexdump to look for unexpected nulls or other weirdness and found nothing

ffmpeg details:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.11-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
```

I updated ffmpeg to 4.4.3 and tried again, same result.

Comment: I am using FFmpeg version 5.1.2 (in Windows), and there is still the same a bug... When converting `ass` file to `srt` file, I am getting a warning *"Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)"*. I am getting an empty file (or just the timestamps). When testing with the following [MKV sample](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/raw-attachment/ticket/5056/sample.mkv) from the following [ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5056), and executing `ffmpeg -y -i sample.mkv test.srt`, the SRT file looks valid. Try MKV to SRT with updated FFmpeg.